# How does one find the Service Principal Name based on the service's URL in Kerberos?

Tags: kerberos

I wonder, when I'm in a Kerberos realm, and I for example type a URL of some service in the organization in my browser, how do the browser know the Service Principal Name so it'll know what to send to the KDC?

Comment: For SPNego _(Kerberos and/or Microsoft NTLM over HTTP)_ the expected SPN is `HTTP/<hostname-shown-in-URL>@<realm-associated-to-that-hostname-based-on-rules-expressed-in-krb5.conf>`

Answer (score 0):

1. The prerequisite is - the service principal name must be attached to one of the users  - usually system users. Checkout `setspn` command details for more. 
   Usually the SPN format is <service class>/<host>:<port>/<service name>.

   E.g. HTTP/MYHOST.DOMAIN.COM
   If you are creating a keytab, check `ktpass` command for windows. It takes spn in the format <service class>/<host>:<port>/<service name>@<REALM>

   By invoking these commands, KDC now knows about your service.

   More about SPN - [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/name-formats-for-unique-spns).
2. When the url is invoked from the browser, the server returns `HTTP 401:Negotiate`
   The browser now knows that the server expects kerberos (or ntlm) token.
3. Usually client(such as a desktop) maintains the Kerberos token cache locally. When the user logs in to the machine using credentials, the TGT (plus some tickets for system services) are stored in this cache. 
   Note that the tokens are issued based on the service (SPN).
4. Browser looks up for the kerberos token corresponding to the accessed service in this cache. 
   If token is found, it is returned to the server. 
   If not found, then windows(system) contacts the kdc, brings the token for this service, puts it in the cache and it is made available to the browser. 
   Note that the system already has user's TGT so user is not prompted for the credentials this time.

Comment: Not `<protocol>`, but `<serviceClass>`.